# How test a component using the useReducer hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-hooks-testing-library

## Reducer

```js
// src/reducers/FooReducer.js

export function FooReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update': {
      return action.newState;
    }
// ... other actions
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown action type');
  }
}
```

## Component

```js
// src/components/BarComponent.js

export function BarComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FooReducer, []);

  return (
    {state.map((item) => (<div />))}
  );
}
```

## Test

```js
// src/components/BarComponent.test.js

it('should render as many divs as there are items', () => {
  act(() => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useReducer(FooReducer, [1]));
    const [, dispatch] = result.current;
    wrapper = mount(<BarComponent />);
    dispatch({type: 'update', newState: [1, 2, 3]});
  });

  expect(wrapper.find(div)).toHaveLength(3);
});
```

The above test example does not work, but serves to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. and would actually render 0 div, as the initial state declared in the component contains 0 items.

1. How would I go about modifying a reducer's state or changing the initialState it is deployed with for testing purposes?
2. I am used to Redux reducers being used throughout multiple components, but useReducer needs a passed initialState... which raises the question: Is react-hook's reducer usable through multiple components as a single instance or will it always be 2 separate instances?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your example, you're trying to test two things at the same time, which would be better off as separate tests: A unit test for your reducer, and a component test where the component uses the reducer.

> 1. How would I go about modifying a reducer's state or changing the initialState it is deployed with for testing purposes?

Similar to a Redux reducers, your reducer is easily unit testable since you're exporting it as a pure function. Just pass in your initial state into the `state` argument, and your action into `action`:

```
it('returns new state for "update" type', () => {
  const initialState = [1];
  const updateAction = {type: 'update', newState: [1, 2, 3] };
  const updatedState = fooReducer(initialState, udpateAction);
  expect(updatedState).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
});
```

You could also test it in the context of `useReducer` if you prefer:

```
it('should render as many divs as there are items', () => {
  act(() => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useReducer(FooReducer, [1]));
    const [state, dispatch] = result.current;
    dispatch({type: 'update', newState: [1, 2, 3]});
  });

  expect(state).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
  // or expect(state).toHaveLenth(3) if you prefer
});
```

> 2. I am used to Redux reducers being used throughout multiple components, but useReducer needs a passed initialState... which raises the question: Is react-hook's reducer usable through multiple components asa single instance or will it always be 2 separate instances?

Here's how `useReducer` is different from Redux: You can reuse the reducer itself, but if you have multiple `useReducer`s, the `state` and `dispatch` returned from each one, as well as the initial state, will be separate instances.

In order to test that your BarComponent updates when the reducer updates, you'll need a way to trigger `dispatch` from within the component, since you're calling `useReducer` inside your component. Here's an example:

```
export function BarComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FooReducer, []);

  const handleUpdate = () => dispatch({type: 'update', newState: [1, 2, 3]})

  return (
    <>
      {state.map((item) => (<div key={item} />))}
      <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Click to update state</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
it('should render as many divs as there are items', () => {
  wrapper = mount(<BarComponent />);

  expect(wrapper.find('div')).toHaveLength(0);

  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');

  expect(wrapper.find('div')).toHaveLength(3);
});
```

This probably isn't very realistic, since I'm hardcoding the new array in the component itself, but hopefully it gives you the idea!

Comment: Thanks for the second answer. As for the first, I have already tested my reducer individually, thx anyways ;). The answer to the secondquestion does raise a concern as to how I have implemented everything, perhaps going overkill with a reducer instead of a state and props.